# Dynamic filter keeps hiding my rows - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The moment I type in the text box my rows become hidden and don't come back after clearing the text box. I used the same exact code on a previous table in a different sheet and it worked flawlessly. I believe the error stems from me copying and pasting the entire table into a different sheet and tweaking the code for the new table. I checked on the linked cell and made sure to change the table name. What am I missing?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Customers").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=[C2] & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, please. It will use `DblClick` event. Otherwise, the `Change` event will be triggered by any character you input. Now, after setting the filter criteria in the text box, **you should double click inside it**:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean
 Dim Tb As ListObject

 Set Tb = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Customers")
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
    Tb.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
  Else
    Tb.Range.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=CStr([C2]), Operator:=xlFilterValues
  End If
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I typed Tb.AutoFilter.ShowAllData instead and it worked for not hiding my rows, but it's still not showing my search results.

Comment: @Nancy I used your code. I understood that it works... But are you sure that the criteria should not be connected to the TextBox value?

Comment: @Nancy is "C2" value in the first column of "Customers" table?

Comment: How would you suggest doing it? I tried TextBox1.Value but I got an error, I'm not very familiar with VBA syntax.

Comment: No, C2 is a cell outside the table

Comment: @Nancy: Forget about this aspect now, please. Let us understand where is the problem. Use the code as it is and try answering my clarification questions, please.

Comment: @Nancy: OK. It may be outside. Are there  such values in the first column of your table?

Comment: Yes, there are only three values at the moment, 1001, 1002, 1003, nothing complicated.

Comment: @Nancy: And **what value is in "C2"**? If one of the three mentioned above, are they formatted in the same way? I mean Text or General...

Comment: C2 is linked to the text box in its properties, so any value I type in the textbox will automatically be displayed in C2.

Comment: @Nancy: Then, here is the problem... When you type 1, the code use it as filter criteria. When you type 0, the code does the same, until the text will be the one you need it. But, **I asked you about the format of the respective cell, against the column you try filtering**...

Comment: Oh you're totally right, I did not realize this because the cells in my previous sheet start with letters. They were both general, I tried making both text but that did not work.

Comment: @Nancy: Please, try the updated code. It forces the filter to be a string (as it should) and `AutoFilter` does not allow wild character for `Criteria1`...

Comment: @Nancy: Pease, take care: I change d the `Change` event with `DblClick`, one. Now, the code lets you input as many character you want, and the event will be triggered by **double clicking inside the text box**.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly!

Comment: @Nancy: Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accapted answer**. Im this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the solution works...

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm fairly new to Stack Overflow.